# Linux Folder/Package Management

Tags: linux, package, package-managers

I'm looking for a way to store all my applications files within a single folder. However, when someone clicks on the folder I want the application inside the folder to open up as opposed to open the folder itself. I want to keep all dependancies and files inside this folder at all times.

I'm doing this because I'm going to be deploying a couple applications on a common framework and want to ensure that they are together and independent of the distribution have all requirements.

Comment: Sounds like you think you are smarter than all those people who contributed to the current state of how software is deployed and installed. Don't get this wrong, think about it instead: there might be a reason why things are handled different.

Comment: You're essentially breaking the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). The distribution closest to what you want is [GoboLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoboLinux). Some of the stuff you want like "*when someone clicks on the folder I want the application inside the folder to open up*" is just *really really weird*.

Comment: You also said: "*I want to keep all dependancies and files inside this folder at all times.*" - What about `glibc`? What about if 10 different applications need to use the same library? Have 10 copies of them, one for each application?

Comment: @ArjunShankar -- I am breaking the traditional way of doing things but in my exact situation it is acceptable. I'm ok with not abiding by standards. I have looked into GoboLinux but it is dormant unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are directories, and directories are distinct from files.  There's no way to redirect a directory to an executable file.  However, you can make a hidden directory (begin name with ".") and use an executable file to provide access to that directory.  The directory will then not appear in window manager folders, just the application.  However, window managers will not misrepresent the executable file as a directory.

Comment: Certainly it is possible to have an application inside a folder open the way he describes. It is just very unusual. All you have to do is install a handler and register it as default action for a folder. The handler can have its own logic.

Comment: Thanks DJ Connel, that actually works very well. I can keep the working directory then add a executable outside the folder to represent the folder.